# iOS 11 UITableViewController inside UINavigationController push/pop animation issue

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, xcode9

I have a UINavigationController with a UITableViewController as the rootViewController.

When pushing to a UIViewController from selecting on of the UITableViewCells, the animation is buggy.

When popping back, the same behaviour occurs, and you can see from the image that the UITableView is showing incorrectly.

Has anyone seen this at all? I am using standard boilerplate code and doing nothing special.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is incorrect and buggy in that? Please elaborate.

Comment: Does the new VC have a transparent background?

Comment: @PGDev please see updated post with GIF. Thanks

Comment: @NSAdi thank you - looks like that was the problem.